# Spring cloud Kafka streams binder health is "UNKNOWN"

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

We are using 2.1.3 version for spring cloud stream kafka streams -

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
```

application.yml has property set -

```
management.health.binders.enabled = true
management.health.kafka.enabled = true
```

But we are still get the status as UNKNOWN for kafka binders -

```
"binders": {
      "status": "UNKNOWN",
      "details": {
        "ktable": {
          "status": "UNKNOWN"
        },
        "kstream": {
          "status": "UNKNOWN"
        },
        "globalktable": {
          "status": "UNKNOWN"
        }
      }
    }
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

The health indicators for Kafka Streams family of binders only went into the 2.2 line. Any chance you can upgrade to 2.2 from 2.1.3? [Here](https://github.com/schacko-samples/s1p-2019-scst-kafka-talk/tree/master/kafka-streams-word-count) is an application where the health indicators are working. This is using the 3.0 snapshots, but 2.2 also should work. When running this app, I am getting the output as below.

```
curl --silent http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/ | jq .
{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
    "binders": {
      "status": "UP",
      "components": {
        "globalktable": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "threadState": "RUNNING",
            "standbyTasks": {},
            "activeTasks": {
              "partitions": [
                "partition=0, topic=process-applicationId-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition"
              ],
              "taskId": "1_0"
            },
            "threadName": "process-applicationId-fa4e65eb-6060-43f0-94eb-4c4bf1497613-StreamThread-1"
          }
        },
        "kstream": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "threadState": "RUNNING",
            "standbyTasks": {},
            "activeTasks": {
              "partitions": [
                "partition=0, topic=process-applicationId-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition"
              ],
              "taskId": "1_0"
            },
            "threadName": "process-applicationId-fa4e65eb-6060-43f0-94eb-4c4bf1497613-StreamThread-1"
          }
        },
        "ktable": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "threadState": "RUNNING",
            "standbyTasks": {},
            "activeTasks": {
              "partitions": [
                "partition=0, topic=process-applicationId-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition"
              ],
              "taskId": "1_0"
            },
            "threadName": "process-applicationId-fa4e65eb-6060-43f0-94eb-4c4bf1497613-StreamThread-1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
       ...
      }
    },
    "ping": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  }
}
```

Note - The issue mentioned in the comments below where multiple processor's health information is not shown is addressed in the latest snapshots of the binder (3.0.0) and will be available as part of RC1.

Comment: It works  but doesn't display status for all stream listener - 
\n

details": {
"threadState": "RUNNING",
"activeTasks": {
"partitions": [
"partition=0, topic=app-paysummary.sub"
],
"taskId": "0_0"
},
"threadName": "app-repository-service-1765507206.paysummary.sub--StreamThread-2"
}
`

Comment: tasks running for multiple listeners -
[app-repository-service.member.sub-StreamThread-2] stream-thread [app-repository-service.membersummary.sub-StreamThread-2] partition assignment took 5 ms.
 current active tasks: [0_0, 0_1]
 current standby tasks: []
 previous active tasks: []

[app-repository-service.memberaudit.sub-StreamThread-4] stream-thread [app-repository-service.memberaudit.sub-StreamThread-4] partition assignment took 7 ms.
 current active tasks: [0_0, 0_1]
 current standby tasks: []
 previous active tasks: []

Comment: I also don't see any metrics related to stream - "stream.metrics.commit.total". Not sure if I am missing any specific property.

Comment: Did you add `management.endpoint.health.show-details: ALWAYS`?

Comment: Streams metrics is a very latest feature and is only available on the latest snapshots (3.0)

Comment: Yes, I added the property. I can see the KStream details of one of the stream listener instead of two with different application-id on same application. I also tried with your sample app, creating two input bindings on same word topic with different application-id.

Comment: I pushed a PR for review - https://github.com/schacko-samples/s1p-2019-scst-kafka-talk/pull/1. I have updated the comments with health response when both listeners are up and when one of the listener is down. Though it shows status as DOWN but it doesn't  show which listener is down.

Comment: Thank you for spotting this. It turned out to be a bug where the information from the first processor is overwritten. We will address this soon.

Comment: Also happens with `spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder` version 1.2.8 or 2.0.0-beta1.  I have 2 binders, maybe that is why?